# Aborting a Batch Job during a chunk-based step

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-batch, chunks

I have a somewhat linear job set up in Spring Batch that consists of several steps. If, at any point, a single step fails, the job should fail.

The steps consist of a number of tasklets followed by a chunk-based step. I.e.:

- Step 1

  - Tasklet 1
- Step 2

  - Tasklet 2
- Step 3

  - Reader
  - Processor
  - Writer

If something goes wrong, the obvious thing to do is throw an Exception. Spring Batch will handle this and log everything. This behaviour, particularly printing the stack trace, is undesirable, and it would be better if the Job could be ended gracefully with the Status set to `FAILED`.

The Tasklets currently set the `ExitStatus` directly on the `StepContribution`. They are also built using a flow (which wasn't ideal, but the steps continue unhindered otherwise). The issues can then be handled directly in the Tasklet.

However, we have no access to the `StepContribution` in the chunk-based approach. We only have the `StepExecution`. Using `setExitStatus` does nothing here.

We are using the builders (`JobBuilerFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory`), not the XML setups.

#### The potential solutions:

1. Tell or configure Batch how to handle exceptions (not to print a stack trace).
2. Catch the exception in a listener. Unfortunately, the exception has already been caught by Spring Batch by the time it gets to the `@AfterStep`.
3. Tell the step/job that we do not want to continue (e.g. setting a value in the execution context or an alternative for the `StepContribution`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to stop the job is to throw an exception. There was no other graceful way of telling Spring Batch "This job is done, it failed, go directly to Failed, do not pass GO, etc."

Although not a direct solution to the original problem, one can use the `.exceptionHandler()` of a `StepBuilder` to gain more control over the exceptions you throw, e.g. logging them.

```
public class LogAndRethrowExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(...);

    @Override
    public void handleException(RepeatContext repeatContext, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.error(throwable.getMessage());
        throw throwable;
    }
}
```

This way you may, in theory, hide the stack traces produced by Spring Batch but still show the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can explore below two options.

**Option 1 :** You Can use `noSkip` **Exception**.

This Explicitly prevent certain exceptions (and subclasses) from being skipped
Throw some specific Exception for which you want to fail the job.

This is how you can configure hat

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                .<POJO, POJO> chunk(1000)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant()
                .noSkip(YourCustomException.class)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(100)
```

****Option 2** :** You can use set the exit status to **FAILED** for error flow   in after step is completed

```
public class MyStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {


    if(allIsGood()) // 
    {
         return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
    else if (someExceptionOrErrorCase()){   

        return ExitStatus.FAILED;
    }
 }

 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The first case is unfortunately the same as what we have at the moment. Without fault tolerance, the builder will simply perform `noSkip` on all exceptions, which is the desired behaviour. It will, however, still print out the stack trace. In the second example, using the `afterStep` (did you mean the `@AfterStep annotation?), the whole step will still be completed. We want the job to fail after the first chunk fails.

Comment: for the case 2 - you can use ChunkListener instead StepExecutionListener. put your logic in afterChunk method.   @option 1 :  i am not sure why option1 is not working for you . if exception mentioned in noSkip is thrown  then batch will automatically fail.

Comment: The ExitStatus cannot be changed in a ChunkListener. That means the step isn't stopped at all. It will continue to read/process, even if you prevent it from writing (or whichever phase of the chunk you stop). As for `noSkip`/`skip`, the job will fail, but we do not want the stack trace. We would like to handle it ourself. Fortunately I've found the solution already, but thank you for your help.

Comment: @Druckles, would you be so kind as to share your solution?

Comment: @AndrewCotton I'm afraid my comment is misleading; we didn't find *the* solution, simply *a* solution: we decided in the end to live with the stack traces in the log. I can, however, post how we got a little more control from the exception handling.

Comment: @Druckles, thank you very much for the response. I just didn't want any research or efforts to go to waste by not sharing them here. Thanks for the answer you added as well.

Comment: Quite right. I think I was hoping for a more definitive/productive response to my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ended up adding conditions and throwing `JobInterruptedException` in both Reader and Processor

```java
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException;

public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<String> {

  @Override
  public String read() throws Exception {
    // ...

    // if ("condition to stop job") {
      throw new JobInterruptedException("Aborting Job", BatchStatus.ABANDONED);
    // }
  }

}
```